# Finding Duplicate Values in XML Column

Tags: sql-server, xml

In my SQL Server DB I have table with an XML column. The XML that goes in it is like the sample below:

```
<Rows>
      <Row>
           <Name>John</Name>
      </Row>
      <Row>
           <Name>Debbie</Name>
      </Row>
      <Row>
           <Name>Annie</Name>
      </Row>
      <Row>
           <Name>John</Name>
      </Row>
</Rows>
```

I have a requirement that I need to find the occurrence of all rows where the XML data has duplicate entries of `<Name>`. For example, above we have 'John' twice in the XML.

I can use the `exist` XML statement to find 1 occurrence, but how can I find if it's more than 1? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To identify any table row that has duplicate `<Name>` values in its XML, you can use `exist` as well:

```
exist('//Name[. = preceding::Name]')
```

To identify *which* names are duplicates, respectively, you need `nodes` and `CROSS APPLY`

```sql
SELECT
  t.id,
  x.Name.value('.', 'varchar(100)') AS DuplicateName
FROM
  MyTable t
  CROSS APPLY t.MyXmlColumn.nodes('//Name[. = preceding::Name]') AS x(Name)
WHERE
  t.MyXmlColumn.exist('//Name[. = preceding::Name]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
(SELECT tbl.col.value('.[1]', 'varchar(100)') as name
 FROM   yourtable
 CROSS APPLY xmlcol.nodes('/Rows/Row/Name') as tbl(col))

select name
from cte
group by name
having count(name) > 1
```

We first use the `nodes` function to convert from XML to relational data, then use `value` to get the text inside the `Name` node. We then put the result of the previous step into a CTE, and use a simple `group by` to get the value with multiple occurences.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/EHWM38111)

Comment: @Tomalak Yeah it supports a lot of languages and even has autocomplete for C#. Very handy!